# why IR receiver keeps recording IR signal of value zero when no IR signal has been transmitted?

Tags: c++, arduino, infrared

I am currently working on a project whereby i have 2 Arduino connected via I2C. An Arduino mega 2560 which is the master and an UNO which is the slave. An IR receiver is connected to the UNO which capture IR signal from a remote and send the signal received to the MEGA for some processing. However, even though there is no IR signal being transmitted, the IR receiver keeps recording IR signal of value 0. Is this issue because of a hardware issue or am i missing something in the code?. To be noted is that the Arduino mega request for IR signal from the UNO every 3 seconds. The job of the MEGA is to validate whether the signal received is the one which should be transmitted by the Arduino UNO. This functionality is being used to simulate controlling IR devices in a room. Below is the code of the slave UNO:

```
IRrecv My_receiver(2);
IRdecode My_decoder;
String wireDecoderSignal = "";
String valueFromMaster;
long wireDecoderSignalValue;


void setup() {


  Wire.begin(5);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
  My_receiver.enableIRIn();


}

void loop() {

  if (My_receiver.GetResults(&My_decoder))
  { //if (My_receiver.GetResults(&My_decoder)) starts

    My_decoder.decode();
    if (My_decoder.value != 4294967295 )
    { // if (My_decoder.value != 4294967295) starts


      wireDecoderSignal = String(My_decoder.value, HEX);
      wireDecoderSignalValue = My_decoder.value;
      Serial.println(wireDecoderSignal);


    } // if (My_decoder.value != 4294967295) ends
      My_receiver.resume();
  }//if (My_receiver.GetResults(&My_decoder)) ends



}


void requestEvent()
{
  if (wireDecoderSignal.length() == 8)
  {

    Serial.println("sending" + wireDecoderSignal);
    Wire.write(wireDecoderSignal.c_str());
    wireDecoderSignal = "";



  }

  else
  {

    Serial.println("SENDING 11111111");
    Wire.write("11111111");



  }

}

void receiveEvent(int howManyBytes)
{
  while (Wire.available())
  {
    valueFromMaster += (char)Wire.read();
  }
  if (valueFromMaster == "T" || valueFromMaster == "F")
  {
    Serial.println("VALUE FROM MASTER IS:" + valueFromMaster);
    valueFromMaster = "";
    wireDecoderSignalValue = 0;




  }

  else if (valueFromMaster.length() == 8)
  {
    // code to transmitting IR signal....signal received from mobile phone to MEGA to here
    // unsigned long value=strtoul(valueFromMaster.c_str(), 0, 32);
    // Serial.println(value);

    long decValue = 0;
    int nextInt;

    for (int i = 0; i < valueFromMaster.length(); i++) {

      nextInt = int(valueFromMaster.charAt(i));
      if (nextInt >= 48 && nextInt <= 57) nextInt = map(nextInt, 48, 57, 0, 9);
      if (nextInt >= 65 && nextInt <= 70) nextInt = map(nextInt, 65, 70, 10, 15);
      if (nextInt >= 97 && nextInt <= 102) nextInt = map(nextInt, 97, 102, 10, 15);
      nextInt = constrain(nextInt, 0, 15);

      decValue = (decValue * 16) + nextInt;
    }

    valueFromMaster = "";
  }
  else if (valueFromMaster.indexOf("on") >= 0 || valueFromMaster.indexOf("off") >= 0)
  {
    // code to turn light on or off based signal received from MEGA which in turn receives signal from mobile
    if (valueFromMaster.indexOf("on") >= 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);

    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
    }
    valueFromMaster = "";
  }

}
```